# search button moving away from search bar

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using bootstrap i have search bar and button but when i minimize the browser or when open developer tools in responsive way the search button moving away from search bar how to make them together?

```html
<!--START SEARCH-->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="float: center">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li>
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--END SEARCH-->
```

Comment: You may add style="display:block;width:200px" to your div with the class input-group (you may adjust the 200px to a value that is width enough for your search field). Or do you want to have the width of your search field to be responsive?

Comment: yes i want all of them responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this. The calc() style attribute ensures, that there is always enough space for your button.

```
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" style="width: calc(100% - 80px);display: inline-block;" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-btn" style="width: 60px;display: inline-block;">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You will have to adapt the pixel numbers and probably will not need the width attribute for the .input-group, as you use bootstrap.